# Better way to strip leading character, new line, cr from QBytearray

Tags: python, pyqt, qprocess, qbytearray

If I only convert the QBytearray to str then the output looks like this: `b'Enter an input A,B,C:\r\n'`

I can get rid of the `\r\n` by using QBytearray.simplified() then the output looks like this :`b'Enter an input A,B,C:'`

In order to remove the last `b' '` I have to only `print string[2:-1]` output:`Enter an input A,B,C:`

These seems like a long way to go about it: simplified,convert to string,strip array. Is there a better method? Currently the data is coming from a Qprocess and being appending to a textBrowser.

```
s = self.process.readAll()
s = s.simplified()
self.itpBrowser.append(str(s)[2:-1])
```

Comment: How are you converting the `QBytearray` to a string?

Comment: try with bytearray({your QBytearray}).decode()

Comment: @l'L'l I'm converting it to string with str(s)

Comment: @eyllanesc bytearray({your QBytearray}).decode() worked I'll have to see which method is most efficient as I still have to convert to string

Comment: just checked no long have to convert to string, that seems like a good solution.

Comment: `s.data().decode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bytearray({your QBytearray}).decode()`

Comment: @Andie2302 
I asked the author, this comment that the solution works but is waiting for other options to choose the best.

Comment: @Andie2302 You should read the comments before expressing your opinion.